# Rename two files

Tags: scripting

I would like to rename two files files by using a script.

E.g.

```
mv plugin-cfg.xml plugin-cfg2.xml
```

and

```
mv plugin-cfgbk.xml plugin-cfg.xml
```

I need to do this in multiple directories.

Question: How can I do this with just  one command in each directory instead of two?

Comment: And what is the question / problem?

Comment: What is preventing you from putting those two commands in a script?

Comment: I need to do this in multiple directories and was hoping I could run just one command in each dir instead of 2.

Comment: I can I run these 2 commands in just one go?

Comment: You're right, this question is basic. There's nothing wrong with that if you're willing to learn, though. May I suggest [some reading](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/Bash-Beginners-Guide.pdf) ?

Comment: @scottmarriott You can have a "script" do the directory changes, too: `for dir in /dir1 /dir2 /dir3; do pushd "$dir"; mv plugin-cfg.xml plugin-cfg2.xml; mv plugin-cfgbk.xml plugin-cfg.xml; popd; done

Answer (score 1):

```
bash-[41]$ touch myscript.sh
bash-[42]$ chmod +x myscript.sh
bash-[43]$ echo '#!/usr/bin/env bash' > myscript.sh
bash-[44]$ echo 'mv plugin-cfg.xml plugin-cfg2.xml' >> myscript.sh
bash-[45]$ echo 'mv plugin-cfgbk.xml plugin-cfg.xml' >> myscript.sh
bash-[46]$ ./myscript.sh
```

**EDIT FOR CLARITY**

Above was intended to be a simple answer to a simple question.  Longer answer.
Creating a directory is up to the user, but you do need to create a script.  Easiest way is to use the `touch` command to create the file with the default `umask`, and use `chmod` to make it executable.

Run in shell:

touch myscript.sh
   chmod +x myscript.sh

Then edit the script and add the following lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash 
mv plugin-cfg.xml plugin-cfg2.xml
mv plugin-cfgbk.xml plugin-cfg.xml
```

Once the script is created, run it in the shell as:

```
./myscript.sh
```

or

```
bash myscript.sh
```

The first line of the script is the `interpreter directive`, commonly referred to as the `shebang` line.  This is the line that tells the shell how to execute the script.  In this case, this is a simple shell script, which runs a shell compatible interpreter to simply run commands as they would be executed from the shell.

In it's simplest guise, that is the gist of a shell script.  To run a batch of commands exactly as they would be run from the shell prompt.  With more complexity in the script come such additions as checking exit codes, and command output, using `if statements` and cases to make dynamic decisions on the next action, based on the outcome of a previous test or action.

Comment: thanks for that. Please excuse my stupid question. So I need to mkdir myscript.sh and put your txt in it?

Comment: @scottmarriott: "Scripts" are just plain text files which optionally have a shebang and are executable.

Comment: @TimKennedy So I need to mkdir myscript.sh and put your txt in it?

Comment: @scottmarriott - `mkdir` is for making directories. `touch` creates an empty file, and the `echo` commands append the lines of text to the files. Alternatively, you can use your favorite text editor to create the script.

Comment: More to the point, if you execute the commands in this answer, you will have a script file which you can execute from each directory where you want to do the two renames. Note that you'll have to strip the prompt (`bash-[xx]$` here) from each line, or it won't work.

Comment: @MattDMo thanks for explain that. It didt work tho as I am not using bash I think.:/usr/tmp $ bash-[41]$ touch myscript.sh ksh: bash-[41]$: not found. :/usr/tmp $ bash-[42]$ chmod +x myscript.sh ksh: bash-[42]$: not found. (no_env):/usr/tmp $ bash-[43]$ echo '#!/usr/bin/env bash' > myscript.sh ksh: bash-[43]$: not found. (no_env):/usr/tmp $ bash-[44]$ echo 'mv Orginal.txt backup.txt' >> myscript.sh ksh: bash-[44]$: not found. (no_env):/usr/tmp $ bash-[45]$ echo 'mv New.txt Orginal.txt' >> myscript.sh ksh: bash-[45]$: not found. (no_env):/usr/tmp $ bash-[46]$ ./myscript.sh

Comment: is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just say "open this file in a text editor and stick these lines in it"? Assembling the whole thing via echo's is odd

Comment: was trying to provide a simple answer.  I'll edit for clarity.

Comment: sorry @scottmarriott.  i gave you a terribly unclear answer.  hopefully the edit provides you the information you need to successfully execute your task.

Comment: Thank you all have learnt alot from this much appreciated, have managed to get it working thanks again :)

Comment: Is there any reason why `touch` is needed? `echo` will create the file and you can just chmod it at the end.

Comment: @terdon That's probably just courtesy towards the cautious friends of `noclobber`... 8-)